# Cannot add iframe in a blocktext

Tags: iframe

I want to add an iframe in a block text on the Text tab as follows :

[image]

But when I apply the updates the iframe disappears, it's like I have never added this part of code :

```
<iframe src="xxxx" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Can you guys please help me figure out what is the origin of this issue?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress.SE zakaria mouqcit. Our site is different from most. If you have not done so yet consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help).